# Pushing Data from GPS to web app

Tags: google-maps, web-applications, gps, serial-port

I have a GPS device connected to my laptops USB port. As I move I would like to transfer the data read by this device to a web application in real time. What simple strategy could I use to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

A simple strategy is [gpsd daemon](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/) and [gps3 python interface](https://github.com/wadda/gps3), but the nature of the question elicits subjective answers.  There might be simpler/better means.

But, along that vain, you could also gather an idea from *gegps3.py*, in the gps3 github repository, which creates `kml` files for realtime Google Earth use.  A bright spark can figure something out, and it doesn't get much easier than that.